# Why XML tag data inside this <![CDATA[]]>

Tags: xml

I have seen in many XML file has the data inside this `<![CDATA[ ]]>`. What is the use of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Wikipedia

A CDATA section starts with the following sequence:

```
<![CDATA[
```

and ends with the first occurrence of the sequence:

```
]]>
```

All characters enclosed between these two sequences are interpreted as characters, not markup or entity references. For example, in a line like this:

```
<sender>John Smith</sender>
```

the opening and closing "sender" tags are interpreted as markup. However, if written like this:

```
<![CDATA[<sender>John Smith</sender>]]>
```

then the code is interpreted the same as if it had been written like this:

```
&lt;sender&gt;John Smith&lt;/sender&gt;
```

Check out the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) page for more details.

Answer (score 3):

See [*CDATA at Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data, not markup.

That means the parser will not interpret any data contained in `<![CDATA[ ]]>`.

Lets say you want to store HTML as text in an XML document. This is wrong:

```
<root>
    <myhtml>
        <div><b>Foo bar</b></div>
    </myhtml>
</root>
```

The parser would try to parse `<div><b>Foo bar</b></div>` and create DOM elements. It would work in this example, but not for documents that conform to an DTD.

Instead, we want this:

```
<root>
    <myhtml>
        <![CDATA[ <div><b>Foo bar</b></div> ]]>
    </myhtml>
</root>
```

and `<div><b>Foo bar</b></div>` will become the content of a text node.

Answer (score 0):

It allows literal text, including most xml "special characters". it's not part of the "outer" xml data but just text.

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

For instance image that you want to send javascript inside an xml document, since it will most probably contain special chars (<,>,&, etc) the xml parser will produce errors.

With this tag the parser will not parse it and no errors will be produced.