# Printing XML format error

Tags: java

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                + "<methodResponse>"
                + "<fault>"
                + "<value>"
                + "<struct>"
                + "<member>"
                + "<name>faultCode</name>"
                + "<value>"
                + "<int>"
                + "-1"
                + "</int>"
                + "</value>"
                + "</member>"
                + "<member>"
                + "<name>faultString</name>"
                + "<value>"
                + "<string>"
                + "The element type value must be terminated by the matching end-tag </value>"
                + "</string>" + "</value>" + "</member>" + "</struct>"
                + "</value>" + "</fault>" + "</methodResponse>";
```

Here, When i try to add the text The element type value must be terminated by the matching end-tag , it is throwing nullpointer exception. How can i handle this. I hope the following part throwing the error. The problem is with "end-tag ". How can i handle this.

```
+ "<string>"
                    + "The element type value must be terminated by the matching end-tag </value>"
                    + "</string>" +
```

Answer (score 3):

You should handle this by *not* creating XML yourself - you should use an XML API.

You're creating invalid XML by trying to include `</value>` as part of the text without escaping it. It should be `&lt;/value>` - but rather than fix this manually, you should use an XML API when creating XML.

(The `>` *can* be escaped to `&gt;`, but doesn't have to be.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the literals...

```
"The element type value must be terminated by the matching end-tag &lt;/value&gt;"
```

Comment: How can i escape the <> tags. do i need to replace it with &lt; or is there any other way?

Comment: Just as the code example shows, replace "<" with "&lt;" and ">" with "&gt;". You might like to have a read through [XML Escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping)

Comment: I'd using something like `String.replace`, but as Jon says, I'd also use a XML API instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CDATA in your XML string; [XML CDATA](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xml_cdata.cfm) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429385/why-xml-tag-data-inside-this-cdata)